# Copy a folder with all its contents and sub folders

Tags: nsis

just started using NullSoft and im trying to install a folder with its files and subfolder i cant figure out whats wrong can i have help?

```
OutFile "Autoclicker.exe"

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES

Section
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
CopyFiles "C:\Users\cameron\Desktop\NullSoft\PH INSTALLER\Data\Autoclicker\Autoclickr.ink" "$DESKTOP" 
WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\Uninstaller.exe
File /r "C:\Users\cameron\Desktop\NullSoft\PH INSTALLER\Data\Autoclicker\"

SectionEnd 

Section "Uninstall"
Delete $INSTDIR\Autoclicker
Delete $INSTDIR\Uninstaller.exe
SectionEndenter code here
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the problem.. You say *I can't figure out what's wrong*, but you failed to explain what problem you're having..

Answer (score 1):

`InstallDir` should contain the name of your application in its path, not just the root directory you want to install to.

`CopyFiles` copies files from one place on the **end-users machine** to another, it cannot be used to extract files from your installer! It is usually used to copy files from a CD or make a backup copy of something.

When using the `File` instruction with `/r` you should use a wildcard filespec to include all files.

I would suggest that you change your code to something like this:

```
!define MySource "C:\Users\cameron\Desktop\NullSoft\PH INSTALLER\Data\Autoclicker"

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\Autoclicker

Section
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\Uninstaller.exe
File /r "${MySource}\*.*"
SetOutPath $Desktop
File "${MySource}\Autoclickr.ink"
SectionEnd
```

I don't know what a .INK file is but it does not sound like something that belongs on the users desktop. If you actually mean .LNK (a shortcut/link) then you should use the `CreateShortcut` instruction to create the .LNK file:

```
CreateShortcut "$Desktop\Autoclikr.lnk" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
```

Finally, in your uninstaller you must use `RMDir /r` to delete a directory, not `Delete`.

Comment: ok thx i just l just started to use it yesterday and i couldnt find mutch tutorials that would help

Answer (score 0):

As @Anders, stated, you can use the `File /r`to recursively install files. The documentation is located at [NSIS File Reference](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/File)